# How to use R to construct a hidden Markov model (HMM) with continuous distribution of observed variables?

Tags: r, hidden-markov-models, hmmlearn, seqhmm

I need to build a **hidden Markov model** in R, which is divided into 1 and 2, two states. When the hidden state is 1, the observed variables obey the exponential distribution, and when the hidden state is 2, the observed variables obey the Gaussian distribution, which means that observed variables obey continuous distribution.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ldCX.png)

I need to get the **parameters** of the exponential distribution and the Gaussian distribution, and the **most likely sequence of hidden states**.

My first question is: **Which package can meet my need**?

My idea is to use depmisS4 packgage, with below code:

```
mod <- depmix(response = cases ~ 1, data = influenza, nstates = 2, family = list(gaussian(), exp())
              trstart = runif(4))
```

Is my code correct? How do I get a sequence of possible hidden states through the code?

Comment: As far as I know, depmixS4 doesn't include the exponential distribution (based on Table 1 of [the vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/depmixS4/vignettes/depmixS4.pdf)). I also think it can't have different distributions in the different states (for the same variable). One option might be to use the gamma distribution in both states: the exponential is a special case (when the shape is 1) and the normal is a limiting case (when the shape goes to Inf).